# How do I remove the blue line that VSCode is putting on everyline I select?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bkS7.png)

The image says it all. Any line I select turns into a blue line.

I shut VSCode and reopened it to no avail. I was expecting this to fix the issue when it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

`"editor.renderLineHighlight": "none"`

ok

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.